# connect to dockerized postgres db from django

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, macos

i got this error message when i try to connect to dockerized postgres db from outside:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "172.19.0.2", port 5432 failed: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

django settings.py:

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': '172.19.0.2',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'NAME': 'devdb',
        'USER': 'devuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass123',
    }
```

docker-compose:

```
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    volumes:
      - dev-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=devdb
      - POSTGRES_USER=devuser
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass123
```

i did docker-compose up, i tried to change the host ip to localhost but with no success.

i tried to chagne the host ip to localhost,
i checked that the db is created via psql,
i used the ip from docker inspect,
any ideas?

Comment: That seems normal to me: the `docker inspect` IP address is unusable except in one very specific environment (of note, you cannot use it directly whenever you are using Docker Desktop) and you never need to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was on docker-compose file:
works after i added:

```
ports:
  - 5432:5432
```

docker inspect before:

```
            "Ports": {
                "5432/tcp": null
            },
```

docker inspect after:

```
           "Ports": {
                "5432/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5432"
                    }
                ]
            },
```